# .css to .scss ends up .scss.css

Tags: css, sass

I'm just working on a local project following this [tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/jazz-up-a-static-webpage-with-subtle-parallax--webdesign-10195) and it tells me to change three css files:

fluid_skeleton.css => _fluid_skeleton.scss

normalize.css => _normalize.scss

styles.css => styles.scss

When I change the file names from mac's Finder, and open the project back up (I am using Sublime Text 2) the file names are:

fluid_skeleton.css => _fluid_skeleton.scss.css

normalize.css => _normalize.scss.css

styles.css => styles.scss.css

I am new to Sass so I am not sure if I have done something wrong, but I doubt it is supposed to look like this... When I open back up my folder back up in Finder it read without the .css at the end... only in my text editor does it append the extra .css

Is this normal? (i doubt it) and if not how can I fix.

Thanks!

Comment: In Mac Finder, click the file to rename and press enter.  You can change the file name.  See here:  http://osxdaily.com/2010/03/18/how-to-rename-a-file-or-folder-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: @SurrealDreams So i did that, and usually that works without any problem. For some reason the .css is appended at the end when I open in sublime

Comment: I had the same issue, it's a bug (or stupid feature) in Finder. I'm definitely renaming it to *exactly* `file.scss` in Finder, but it keeps adding `.css` to the end. Using the command line works fine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather, you are adding the .scss at the end of file name without changing the extension of the old file. You could rename the file in Mac terminal using

```
mv oldfilename.css newfilename.scss
```